# Unable to configure Outlook to only retrieve email every X minutes

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm trying to configure Outlook to only retrieve new email from the server every X minutes.
Currently emails arrive instantly without me doing anything (like pressing the Send/Receive button). I only need the autoretrieve to be performed every X minutes, I don't need any protection against me purposfully pressing Send/Receive button.

I want to be able to look at Outlook without constantly getting new email. To get new emails in bigger chunks, less frequent. I'm on the "focus" fad.

My account is managed by the company I work for, so installing plugins (like Boomerang) is not an option.

This is how I tried to configure my Sent/Receive Groups:

[image]

Both email accounts are part of the "All Accounts" group.
I even tried to Disable Scheduled Send/Receive all together:
[image]

Still email appear in outlook as soon as they are sent.
Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2302 Build 16.0.16130.20298) 64-bit

What am I missing?
Or is it a conspiracy?

Thanks

Comment: Exchange/outlook is probably allowing MAPI push notifications to update your email.  You are trying to use a PULL model like POP3 has.  There is nothing you can do about it if your client is locked down.  If you are A.D.D. (as I am), close the client.  Open it when you are ready to see updates.

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate the type of email account (Company's MS Exchange, Outlook.com, POP,  MAP, etc.).  Please also confirm that 'Send Immediately When Connected' is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new profile of your account in Outlook.This profile can rule how long you get the messages once.
About creating new profiles, please info this Microsoft Document:[enter link description here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Then run a message trace and view the delivery details of message sent in a specific time. By using it, you can learn about when the messages be sent.It can prevent you miss the important mail.
About configuring message trace ,you can info this Microsoft Document:[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/monitoring/trace-an-email-message/run-a-message-trace-and-view-results?redirectedfrom=MSDN)